# Homebrew, spotlight and upgrading software under /usr/bin/

Tags: macos, bash, homebrew, spotlight

My OS X comes with a version of `git` installed in `/usr/bin`. However, this version is older than the official stable one. I would like to upgrade it.

1. Can I use Homebrew to upgrade this version? Or would Homebrew install `git` in a separate location?

If Homebrew installs git in a separate location:

1. How would my terminal know which version/location of `git` to run? Was I supposed to update `PATH` in my shell after installing brew?
2. How would Spotlight know which version/location of Git to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I use brew to upgrade this version?

No. That is the default version installed by Xcode / developer tools. I would leave it as-is.

> Or would brew install git in a separate location?

Yes, in `/usr/local/bin/git`, which links to a version installed in `/usr/local/Cellar`.

(Note that unlike Homebrew, the official [OS X Git Installer](https://code.google.com/p/git-osx-installer/) installs to `/usr/local/git/bin`.)

> How would my terminal know which version/location of git to run? Was I supposed to update PATH in my shell after installing brew?

Typically you don't need to because Homebrew by default does not ship anything that comes with OS X anyway. But if you want Homebrew commands that are duplicates of native commands to come first, edit your PATH in your `~/.bash_profile`:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

After a restart of the shell or re-sourcing the path, the `git` should come from Homebrew. Run `which -a git` to see all installed Git binaries.

> How would spotlight know which version/location of git to use?

I'm not sure what the purpose would be, since Spotlight is used for finding documents that can be opened in some application—or GUI applications—but `git` by itself cannot be opened.

I suspect that Spotlight does not find any of the `git` executables unless they exist in your user's home directory, e.g. `~/bin`.